# How to update voices and gatekeeper?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

There was an error in the dependency specifications which somehow triggered a [major failure in AppStore.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321529/some-macos-app-store-functions-broken?noredirect=1#comment409716_321529).  Most of those problems are now fixed, but while wrestling with it, I discovered /var/log/install.log

Every time I go to the Updates panel in AppStore, that log shows a detailed record of the scan for updates.  This record always ends with a list of seventeen available updates: 16 Voices and a Gatekeeper configuration.  Yet AppStore still says no updates available.

**How can I get those items to update?**  For the voices, I could probably deselect them and re-add in Preferences, but that seems pretty silly and doesn't help Gatekeeper.  Update: Don't have to deselect voices.  Selecting customize from the voice menu in Speech prefs shows the ones selected, and just clicking OK starts the update.  I'm going to file a bug report that Software Update won't do it.  And I still don't know about Gatekeeper.  That's probably some other obscure location in the preferences.

By the way, part of the AppStore fix was a reinstall of the OS without a disk wipe.  So why did not these items get updated during the reinstall (by internet with Recovery partition)?

Comment: Two days ago, some of the pages at GetSupport.Apple.com had e-mail forms.  But yesterday, only chat and phone (and on chat, they said e-mail hasn't been there for two years).  Phone is not an option for me, and the chat guy said my question had to be discussed with engineering, who are only allowed to use phone.  No chat, no FaceTime, no e-mail.  Or he could make me an appointment at the Apple store—six hours away by train or twenty by bicycle.  (!)